# razor syntax problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i want to clean my code

```
@foreach (System.Data.DataRowView c in (System.Data.DataView)ViewBag.Folders)
{
<tr>
    @if ((Boolean)c.Row["VF_Visible"]) {  
        <td><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "page", new { parent = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"], granParent = c.Row["VF_Parent_ID"] })">@c.Row["SMF_Name"]</a></td>
     } else { 
        <td class="itemUnVisible"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "page", new { parent = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"], granParent = c.Row["VF_Parent_ID"] })">@c.Row["SMF_Name"]</a></td>
    }

    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", new { id = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"] })</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"] })</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Preview", new { id = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"] })</td>
</tr>
}
```

the code that is inside the if is duplicated.
when i leave inside the if just the td without the a tag and the closing tag it's give me an error.

```
@foreach (System.Data.DataRowView c in (System.Data.DataView)ViewBag.Folders)
{
<tr>
    @if ((Boolean)c.Row["VF_Visible"]) {  
        <td>
     } else { 
        <td class="itemUnVisible">
    }
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "page", new { parent = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"], granParent = c.Row["VF_Parent_ID"] })">@c.Row["SMF_Name"]</a></td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", new { id = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"] })</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"] })</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Preview", new { id = c.Row["SMF_VF_ID"] })</td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: ugh..code soup. use a ViewModel, and a display template to get rid of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put non-well-formed HTML inside a block (such as your `<if>`) because Razor won't know where to end the block..

You need to [force the HTML to be treated as literal text](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx):

```
@if ((Boolean)c.Row["VF_Visible"]) {  
    @:<td>
 } else { 
    @:<td class="itemUnVisible">
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some sort of unwritten rule that says that everytime you have an `if` in your view, write a helper:

```
public static HtmlString DetermineCellAction(this HtmlHelper helper, 
    object visibleColumnValue)
{
    // All code below could be much cleaner, this is just an example!

    var visible = (bool)visibleColumnValue;
    var td = "";

    td = (visible) ? "<td if visible>" : "<td if not visible>";

    return new HtmlString(td);
}
```

Then you can just use it like:

```
@foreach (System.Data.DataRowView c in (System.Data.DataView)ViewBag.Folders)
{
<tr>
    @Html.DetermineCellAction(c.Row["VF_Visible"])
    <!-- mode html here -->
</tr>
}
```

Note that the helper is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), in this case extending [`HtmlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx), but you could just as well make it an extension method to `DataRowView` if that where more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like (not tested) ...

```
<td @if((bool)c.Row["VF_Visible"]) { <text>class="itemUnVisible"</text> } >
```

or

Update your ViewModel to be cleaner than using a collection of DataRowView. I'd create a model class which you do all the parsing into in your controller, including calc visibility, and then pass that to your view.

```
public class MyViewRecord
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int ParentId {get;set;}
  // etc.
  public bool Visible {get;set;}
}
```

You can then do something like ...

```
@foreach (MyViewRecord item in ViewBag.Folders)
{
<tr>
    @if (item.Visible) {  
        <text><td></text>
     } else { 
        <text><td class="itemUnVisible"></text>
    }
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "page", new { parent = item.ParentId, granParent = item.GrandParentId })">@item.Name</a></td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", new { id = item.Id })</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Preview", new { id = item.Id })</td>
</tr>
}
```

Hope this helps